# Test a dialog that needs to be forwarded to

Tags: c#, unit-testing, botframework

I've created a dialog that expects to be forwarded to

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using pc.apm.bot.Services;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace pc.apm.bot.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class NewUserDialog : IDialog<string>
    {
        IApmService _apmService;
        LangaugeCodes _langaugeCode;

        public NewUserDialog(IApmService apmService, LangaugeCodes langaugeCode)
        {
            _apmService = apmService;
            _langaugeCode = langaugeCode;
        }

        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            if (new TraceSwitch("apmDiagnostics", "").Level == TraceLevel.Info)
                await context.PostAsync($"Current Dialog: {this.GetType().Name}");

            context.Wait<string>(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
        {
            var userEmail = await result;

            await context.PostAsync(StringResourceService.GetStringResource(StringKeys.NewUserStarted_Key, _langaugeCode));

            var apmId = await _apmService.CreateUserAsync(userEmail.ToLower());

            var UserProvisionedAlfabet_Text = StringResourceService.GetStringResource(StringKeys.UserProvisionedAlfabet_Key, _langaugeCode);
            await context.PostAsync(String.Format(UserProvisionedAlfabet_Text, userEmail));

            context.Done(apmId);
        }
    }
}
```

now the way it works is on a previous dialog I have some logic that decides a new user needs to be provisioned, when that is the case it forwards the users email to the NewUserDialog to do just that.

```
await context.Forward(
    child: new NewUserDialog(), 
    resume: (c, r) => AddProfile(context, result), 
    item: user.Email,
    token: CancellationToken.None);
```

so that all works fine and dandy, the problem i'm having is Unit testing this code; i'm trying to follow what has been laid out in bot builder tests project

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Tests/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.Tests

now i have my test starting, it's just when my NewUserDialog attempts to await the email address the thing fails and and exception is thrown

pc.apm.bot.tests.Test_New_User_Dialog.Create_New_User threw exception: 
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.InvalidTypeException: invalid type: expected System.String, have Activity

so i see that it's a type issue; but i am at a loss as how to pass the email address to the dialog through the test code.

here's my test code

```
using Autofac;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Tests;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
using pc.apm.bot.Dialogs;
using pc.apm.bot.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace pc.apm.bot.tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Test_New_User_Dialog : DialogTestBase
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task Test_method() => Assert.IsTrue(await Task.FromResult(true));

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task Create_New_User()
        {
            var mockApmService = new Mock<IApmService>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            mockApmService
                .Setup(m => m.CreateUserAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns<string>(x => Task.FromResult("123-123"));

            var NewUserDialog = new NewUserDialog(mockApmService.Object, LangaugeCodes.en_US);

            var toBot = DialogTestBase.MakeTestMessage();
            toBot.From.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            Func<IDialog<string>> MakeRoot = () => NewUserDialog;

            using (new FiberTestBase.ResolveMoqAssembly(NewUserDialog))
            using (var container = Build(Options.MockConnectorFactory | Options.ScopedQueue, NewUserDialog))
            {
                using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(container, toBot))
                {
                    DialogModule_MakeRoot.Register(scope, MakeRoot);
                    await Conversation.SendAsync(scope, toBot);

                    var firstResponse = scope.Resolve<Queue<IMessageActivity>>().Dequeue();
                    Assert.IsTrue(firstResponse.Text.Equals("Looks as if you are a new user, let's get you started!"));

                    var secondResponse = scope.Resolve<Queue<IMessageActivity>>().Dequeue();
                    Assert.IsTrue(secondResponse.Text.Equals("A user for pawel.chooch@fake.com has been provisioned in System"));
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

so in short my question is how can you test a dialog that receives a parameter by having it forwarded to it from a parent dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a significant amount of effort, i finally got it,

```
using Autofac;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Tests;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
using pc.apm.bot.Dialogs;
using pc.apm.bot.Services;
using pc.apm.bot.tests.Interfaces;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace pc.apm.bot.tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Test_New_User_Dialog : DialogTestBase
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public async Task Test_method() => Assert.IsTrue(await Task.FromResult(true));

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task Create_New_user_Dialog()
        {
            var mockRootDialog = new Mock<IMessageRecievedDialog<IMessageActivity>>(MockBehavior.Loose);
            var mockApmService = new Mock<IApmService>(MockBehavior.Strict);

            mockApmService.Setup(m => m.CreateUserAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
                          .Returns<string>(x => Task.FromResult("123-123"));

            var NewUserDialog = new NewUserDialog(mockApmService.Object, LangaugeCodes.en_US);
            var userEmail = "pawel.chooch@fake.com";

            mockRootDialog.Setup(d => d.StartAsync(It.IsAny<IDialogContext>()))
                          .Returns<IDialogContext>(
                                context =>
                                {
                                    context.Wait(mockRootDialog.Object.MessageRecievedAsync);
                                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                                });

            mockRootDialog.Setup(d => d.MessageRecievedAsync(It.IsAny<IDialogContext>(), It.IsAny<IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>>()))
                          .Returns<IDialogContext, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>>(async (context, message) =>
                          {
                              var email = await message;
                              await context.Forward(
                                  child: NewUserDialog,
                                  resume: async (c, r) =>
                                  {
                                      Assert.AreEqual("123-123", await r);
                                      c.Done<object>(null);
                                  },
                                  item: email.Text,
                                  token: CancellationToken.None);
                          });

            var toBot = DialogTestBase.MakeTestMessage();

            using (new FiberTestBase.ResolveMoqAssembly(mockRootDialog.Object, NewUserDialog))
            using (var container = Build(Options.MockConnectorFactory | Options.ScopedQueue, mockRootDialog.Object, NewUserDialog))
            using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(container, toBot))
            {
                DialogModule_MakeRoot.Register(scope, () => mockRootDialog.Object);

                var task = scope.Resolve<IPostToBot>();
                toBot.Text = userEmail;
                await task.PostAsync(toBot, CancellationToken.None);

                var firstResponse = scope.Resolve<Queue<IMessageActivity>>().Dequeue();
                Assert.IsTrue(firstResponse.Text.Equals("Looks as if you are a new user, let's get you started!"));

                var secondResponse = scope.Resolve<Queue<IMessageActivity>>().Dequeue();
                Assert.IsTrue(secondResponse.Text.Equals($"A user for {userEmail} has been provisioned in ALFABET"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now my apm service aside, i created an interface IMessageRecievedDialog

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace pc.apm.bot.tests.Interfaces
{
    public  interface IMessageRecievedDialog<T> : IDialog<T>
    {
        Task MessageRecievedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<T> result);
    }
}
```

this was actually not necessary for in the  Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Tests namespace there's an interface "IDialogFrames" which is exactly the same thing. I pulled my inspiration for the solution from the DialogTask_Forward test again from the Microsoft.bot.builder.tests

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task DialogTask_Forward()
{
    var dialogOne = new Mock<IDialogFrames<string>>(MockBehavior.Loose);
    var dialogTwo = new Mock<IDialogFrames<string>>(MockBehavior.Loose);
    const string testMessage = "foo";

    dialogOne
        .Setup(d => d.StartAsync(It.IsAny<IDialogContext>()))
        .Returns<IDialogContext>(async context => { context.Wait(dialogOne.Object.ItemReceived); });

    dialogOne
        .Setup(d => d.ItemReceived(It.IsAny<IDialogContext>(), It.IsAny<IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>>()))
        .Returns<IDialogContext, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>>(async (context, message) =>
        {
            var msg = await message;
            await context.Forward(dialogTwo.Object, dialogOne.Object.ItemReceived<string>, msg, CancellationToken.None);
        });

    dialogOne
        .Setup(d => d.ItemReceived(It.IsAny<IDialogContext>(), It.IsAny<IAwaitable<string>>()))
        .Returns<IDialogContext, IAwaitable<string>>(async (context, message) =>
        {
            var msg = await message;
            Assert.AreEqual(testMessage, msg);
            context.Wait(dialogOne.Object.ItemReceived);
        });


    dialogTwo
        .Setup(d => d.StartAsync(It.IsAny<IDialogContext>()))
        .Returns<IDialogContext>(async context => { context.Wait(dialogTwo.Object.ItemReceived); });

    dialogTwo
        .Setup(d => d.ItemReceived(It.IsAny<IDialogContext>(), It.IsAny<IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>>()))
        .Returns<IDialogContext, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>>(async (context, message) =>
        {
            var msg = await message;
            context.Done(msg.Text);
        });

    Func<IDialog<object>> MakeRoot = () => dialogOne.Object;
    var toBot = MakeTestMessage();

    using (new FiberTestBase.ResolveMoqAssembly(dialogOne.Object, dialogTwo.Object))
    using (var container = Build(Options.None, dialogOne.Object, dialogTwo.Object))
    {
        using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(container, toBot))
        {
            DialogModule_MakeRoot.Register(scope, MakeRoot);
            var task = scope.Resolve<IPostToBot>();
            toBot.Text = testMessage;
            await task.PostAsync(toBot, CancellationToken.None);

            dialogOne.Verify(d => d.StartAsync(It.IsAny<IDialogContext>()), Times.Once);
            dialogOne.Verify(d => d.ItemReceived(It.IsAny<IDialogContext>(), It.IsAny<IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>>()), Times.Once);
            dialogOne.Verify(d => d.ItemReceived(It.IsAny<IDialogContext>(), It.IsAny<IAwaitable<string>>()), Times.Once);

            dialogTwo.Verify(d => d.StartAsync(It.IsAny<IDialogContext>()), Times.Once);
            dialogTwo.Verify(d => d.ItemReceived(It.IsAny<IDialogContext>(), It.IsAny<IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>>()), Times.Once);
        }
    }
}
```

The following link really helped
https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/DevOps-for-the-Bot-Framework/Testing-the-Bot-Framework?term=bot

I'm still not familiar enough with the botframework specific code to really offer an explanation, thus i just took it for granted. Anyway i hope my leg work helps someone else. cheers.

Comment: If anyone can expand my answer or provide a superior one please feel free to share. My solution is shaky  at best.